# Specify cache directory for Go-Glide

Tags: go, glide-golang

Is there a way to specify a cache directory in Glide command ?

`glide install --strip-vendor`

Above command uses ~/.glide/cache directory as cache by default.

Is there a way to specify custom directory to use for cache or is there a way to avoid considering cache directory itself.

I do not want to use `glide cache-clear` command since multiple glide install command might be running in my environment. So this may affect working of another glide install command.

Comment: Looking at the code, by default the users home folder is the cache directory.
https://github.com/Masterminds/glide-report/blob/master/vendor/github.com/Masterminds/glide/path/path.go
Anyway, having multiple projects using the same cache sounds efficient, not sure why you want to have separate caches per repository?

Answer (score 0):

I use GLIDE_HOME=XXX to change it.